# capybara's fill_in method not working as expected

Tags: cucumber, capybara

I have 2 forms in my page. The first form has a field "Username" and the second form has a field "Username:".

When  `fill_in label, :with => value`  is run (where label = "Username:"), the input box labeled "Username" is getting filled instead.

I changed "Username:" to "User name:" but even then "Username" gets filled.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have 2 identically named text inputs on 2 different forms on your page.

I believe `fill_in some_field` will look for an input with a name or ID matching `some_field`, rather than reading an attached label.  *Edit: It does actually look for an attached label - thanks to AlistairH for the correction*

I would suggest the best way to get the behaviour you want is using a `within` block:

```
within 'form1' do
    fill_in 'Username', :with => value
end
```

Replace 'form1' with the name of whichever form contains the textbox you'd like to target.

*I would consider this to be far more reliable, and readable, than relying on the presence of spaces or colons to differentiate between almost identically named elements on the page*

Comment: Actually, from the rubydoc: "Locate a text field or text area and fill it in with the given text The field can be found via its name, id or label text."

Comment: When matching on label name, it is worth checking that the 'for' attribute on the label is referencing the correct input. In any case, having to fields with almost the same label on the same page sounds like a strange UI to me.

Comment: We are using formtastic v1.1.0 which does not support namespace. We cannot upgrade to a newer version of formtastic at this point. Hence the problem.

Comment: I'm not familiar with formtastic, but if it's creating 2 separate form elements, surely they have unique identifiers of some kind?  The HTML ID's would surely be distinct, and you can use that to specify the `within` block.